# css: взаимное расположение блоков

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

есть код:

```
<div class = 'content'>
    <div class = 'block1'></div>
    <div class = 'block2'></div>
    <div class = 'block3'></div>
</div>
```

`block1` фиксированной ширины
`block2` фиксированной высоты

`block2` и `block3` слева от `block1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если задать `block1` другую ширину, остальные блоки должны на это среагировать соответственно.

Подскажите как лучше такой вариант реализовать?

1. делать таблицу или использовать `display: table` не лучший вариант
2. использовать `position` хорошо если никакие блоки меняться не будут
3. использовать `flex` где изначально задать взаимное отношение блоков

Второй вариант реализовал, но в динамике очень неудобно использовать - надо отслеживать все блоки

Думаю, лучше через `flex`, но никак не могу понять как это реализовать. При условии что `block1.width + block2.width < 100%`, т.е. если `block2` будет очень узким не должно случиться так, чтобы `block3` стал сбоку (справа) от `block2`

Подскажите как можно реализовать такую схему через `flex`?

Comment: А разметку менять можно?

Comment: Вообще, `display: grid` отлично подойдёт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Первый вариант** — `Grid`:

```css
.block1 {
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: block1;
  min-height: 70px;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 70px;
  grid-area: block2;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 300px;
  grid-area: block3;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-template-areas: "block1 block2" "block1 block3";
}

@media (max-width: 400px){
  .content {
    display: block;
  }
  .block1,
  .block2,
  .block3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='block1'></div>
  <div class='block2'></div>
  <div class='block3'></div>
</div>
```

**Второй вариант** — `Flexbox`:

```css
.wrp {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 70px;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 300px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrp'>
  <div class='block1 sidebar'></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class='block2'></div>
    <div class='block3'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно было поменять html?))

Comment: Не знаю. Вроде нигде не сказано, что нельзя...

Comment: я просто думал, что есть шаблон и нужно именно к нему стили прописать. А так конечно плюс вам за решение ))

Comment: Может нужно и по шаблону, скоро узнаем)

Comment: Добавил пример на гридах, без изменения разметки

Comment: Забыл добавить, что html менять не хотелось бы :)

Первый вариант здоровский! Правда IE его не поддерживает совершенно, с другой стороны кому нужны эти 1.5% неудачников. Но всё таки хотелось бы универсальное решение.

Comment: @l2banners, первый вариант не подходит, увы, если схлопнуть block1, то два остальных блока не сдвинутся влево :(

Comment: @Zhihar Они схлопнуться как угодно при помощи медиа запросов.

Comment: @Zhihar Добавил медиа для первого примера. Все блоки становятся в колону один под другой, когда ширина окна меньше 400 пикселей

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body, .content {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto 1fr / auto 1fr;
}

.left {
  background: orange;
  width: 100px;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.top {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.other {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="other"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: тут как раз тот самый `display: grid`

хотя наверно его и надо применять, раз он для этого создан

Comment: Его даже можно под IE 10-11 подогнать.